# Regex joining words splitted by whitespace and hyphen

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, whitespace

My string is quite messy and looks something like this:

`s="I'm hope-less and can -not solve this pro- blem on my own. Wo - uld you help me?"`

I'd like to have the hyphen (& sometimes whitespace) stripped words together in one list.. Desired output:

`list = ['I'm','hopeless','and','cannot','solve','this','problem','on','my','own','.','Would','you','help','me','?']`

I tried a lot of different variations, but nothing worked..

`rgx = re.compile("([\w][\w'][\w\-]*\w)")
s = "My string'"
rgx.findall(s)`

Comment: Try `r"\w+(?:'\w+)?|[^\s\w]+"`

Comment: Thanks, but that only solves my issue partially.. I'd like to have "hope-less" and also "pro- blem" as one item in my list: E.g. "problem"

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed that as I was viewing the question on my mobile. I think you need some preprocessing, like `re.sub(r'\b\s*-\s*\b', '', s)`, but since regex does not "know" the English language and this plainly remove hyphens in between word chars, it may remove too much.

Comment: s=s.replace(' - ', '').replace(' -', '').replace('- ', '').replace('-','').replace(' ', ',').split(',')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
[re.sub(r'\s*-\s*', '', i) for i in re.split(r'(?<!-)\s(?!-)', s)]

# ["I'm", 'hopeless', 'and', 'cannot', 'solve', 'this', 'problem', 'on', 'my', 'own.', 'Would', 'you', 'help', 'me?']
```

Two operations here:

1. Split the text based on whitespaces *without hyphens* using both negative lookahead and negative lookbehind.
2. In each of the split word, replace the hyphens with possible whitespaces in front or behind to empty string.

You can see the first operation's demo here: https://regex101.com/r/ayHPvY/2

And the second: https://regex101.com/r/ayHPvY/1

Edit: To get the `.` and `?` to be separated as well, use this instead:

```
[re.sub(r'\s*-\s*','', i) for i in re.split(r"(?<!-)\s(?!-)|([^\w\s'-]+)", s) if i]

# ["I'm", 'hopeless', 'and', 'cannot', 'solve', 'this', 'problem', 'on', 'my', 'own', '.', 'Would', 'you', 'help', 'me', '?']
```

The catch was also splitting the non-alphabets, non-whitespace and not hyphens/apostrophe.  The `if i` is necessary as the split might return some `None` items.

Comment: For downvoter, would appreciate to have the critique on this answer before you downvote.  As far as I can tell I don't see any significant problem with this approach.

Comment: for some reason, I see lots of downvotes on regex tag, for both questions and answers.. dunno why

Comment: Not me downvoted, but I think your output is a little bit different from OP's `Desired output`.

Comment: @Sundeep probably due to a lot of misuse on regex... a lot of questions asks for a regex solution that doesn't call for it, or some regex solutions provided are just badly optimized.  I'll profess I'm not a regex expert myself that's why I'd appreciate others to point out the problem and help me learn instead of just walking away with a downvote.

Comment: @Tiw good point, I didn't notice the `.` and `?` were separated as well.  Seeing as this was accepted, I will see if OP comes back with a comment and update accordingly.

Comment: yeah, I'd also like to know *why* are these being downvoted

Answer (score 1):

Quick, non-regex way to do it would be

```
''.join(map(lambda s: s.strip(), s.split('-'))).split()
```

that is split on hyphens, strip of additional whitespaces, join back into string and split on space, this however doesn't separate dot or question marks.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
>>> s
"I'm hope-less and can -not solve this pro- blem on my own. Wo - uld you help me
?"
>>> list(map(lambda x:re.sub(' *- *','',x), filter(lambda x:x, re.split(r'(?<!-) +(?!-)|([.?])',s))))
["I'm", 'hopeless', 'and', 'cannot', 'solve', 'this', 'problem', 'on', 'my', 'own', '.', 'Would', 'you', 'help', 'me', '?']
```

Above used a simple space `' '`, but use `\s` is better:

```
list(map(lambda x:re.sub('\s*-\s*','',x), filter(lambda x:x, re.split(r'(?<!-)\s+(?!-)|([.?])',s))))
```

`(?<!-)\s+(?!-)` means spaces that don't have `-` before or after.
`[.?]` means single `.` or `?`.

`re.split(r'(?<!-)\s+(?!-)|([.?])',s)` will split the string accordingly, but will have some `None` and empty string `''` inside:

```
["I'm", None, 'hope-less', None, 'and', None, 'can -not', None, 'solve', None, 'this', None, 'pro- blem', None, 'on', None, 'my', None, 'own', '.', '', None, 'Wo - uld', None, 'you', None, 'help', None, 'me', '?', '']
```

This result was directly feed to `filter` to remove `None` and `''`, and then feed to `map` to remove space and `-` inside each word.